# Stunnel with Redis Sentinel

Tags: redis-sentinel, stunnel

Ok so allegedly Redis Setninels now work with TLS. 
I have the Master and Slaves replicating fine with stunnel. 
However, I'm unable to get the Sentinels to communicate with eachother 
as well as the Master.

I have 1 Master, 2 Slaves and 3 Sentinels

Sample of my stunnel.conf

```
pid = /run/stunnel.pid
output = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.log

[Redis server]
cert = /etc/stunnel/ABC_private.pem
accept = xxx.xx.160.77:26280
connect = 127.0.0.1:26280


[Client XYZ Redis Server]
client=yes
cert = /etc/stunnel/XYZ_private.pem

accept = 127.0.0.1:8000
connect = xxx.xx.161.78:6480


# SENTINEL SERVERS

[Client 123 Sentinel Server]
client=yes
cert = /etc/stunnel/123_private.pem

accept = 127.0.0.1:8001
connect = xxx.xx.160.77:26280
```

Sample of my Sentinel configs

```
protected-mode no
bind 127.0.0.1
port 26280
sentinel monitor redisftdev 127.0.0.1 8002 2
```

When I run the following command on the local sentinel:

127.0.0.1:26280> sentinel sentinels redisftdev
(empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:26280>

I can connect no problem to a remote Sentinel, but of course I get the same response

127.0.0.1:8005> sentinel sentinels redisftdev
(empty list or set)

Comment: Ok I got this. Yes Sentinel works with Stunnel. I'm using 4.02. I didn't annouce the ports for my sentinels and slaves.

Comment: Specifically - sentinel announce-port 8003

Where port 8003 is the client bound 127.0.0.1 port
accept = 127.0.0.1:8003
connect = 12.34.56.7:6379

Same with the slaves the redis.conf 
slave-announce-port 8000

Answer (score 0):

Sorry new to this - 
Ok I got this. Yes Sentinel works with Stunnel. I'm using 4.02. I didn't annouce the ports for my sentinels and slaves.
Specifically - 
    sentinel announce-port 8003

Where port 8003 is the client bound 127.0.0.1 port in your stunnel.conf
`accept = 127.0.0.1:8003`
`connect = 12.34.56.7:6379`

Same with the slaves the redis.conf 
`slave-announce-port 8000`

Comment: Do we need announce port for sentinnel using stunnel ?